# Pickling a dict inside a PyQt app

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pickle

I'm attempting to dump a pickle file in my PyQt app only its seems to be completely ignoring the statement.

```
import cPickle as pickle

class MyActions(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        #Create blank dictionary and save it.
        self.employee_dict = {}
        pickle.dump(self.employee_dict, open("pickle file", 'wb'))


        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.emp_display )
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.admin_display)
```

am i doing something wrong here or is pickle just not compatible with dumping dictionaries in side a PyQt gui.

Comment: Exactly what makes you think it's "completely ignoring the statement"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your question doesn't have enough information to go on, I'm willing to bet I know the answer.

You're creating a file called `pickle file` in whatever the current directory happens to be.

Then you're going and looking for the `pickle file` right next to the script, which is in general not going to be the current directory.

In the special case where you're running a script from the command line as `./foo.py` or `python ./foo.py`, of course, the two happen to be the same. But when you double-click a PyQt app, it's… well, that depends on what platform you're on, and a variety of Explorer/Finder/Nautilus/etc. settings (either global, or per-app), but it's generally not going to be the same place the script is.

---

If you just want to force it to write the file next to the script (which is usually a bad idea), you can save the script directory at startup, like this:

```
import os
import sys

scriptdir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

Then, instead of writing to `'pickle file'`, you can write to `os.path.join(scriptdir, 'pickle file')`.

---

However, a better solution is to use a platform-appropriate "app data" directory or "home" or "documents" directory (depending on whether you want the file to be visible to novice users); Qt has nice wrappers that make it easy to do that in the platform-appropriate way with platform-independent code.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. I have only ever used pickle with non-gui apps that i have written and in those cases it inherently saved the pickle file in whichever directory you ran your program from so i was under that assumption. When you say 'use a platform-appropriate "app data" directory or home or documents' you just mean use my path directory to a documents folder or whatever and just use join like above ?

Comment: @DreamPie: This has nothing to do with pickle, or with GUI apps, or even with Python; whenever you specify a filename without a path, in any app, you get a file in the current working directory.

Comment: @DreamPie: Meanwhile, when I say "use a platform-appropriate …", there are three different options there. Pick the appropriate one, use the Qt function that returns that path, then `os.path.join` that path to your filename. I'm pretty sure this is all demonstrated pretty early in the Qt or PyQt tutorial.